# I have an error in laravel Class 'App\post' not found

Tags: laravel-5

When calling the store method,following error displays:

> Class 'App\post' not found

My post controller:

```
use App\post;


class postController extends Controller
{

    public function create()
    {

        return view('posts.create'); 

    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $post=new post; 
       $post->title =$request->title;
       $post->body =$request->body;

       $post->save();

       dd("Hi");

       return Redirect::to('/')->with('success','You have been successfully subscribe to us.');

      }      

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the time to [format your code properly](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). In addition, please add some more details about your issue. Is `App\post` defined? Did you run `dump-autoload`?

Answer (score 1):

First you should change

```
$post=new post;
```

to

```
  $post = new post();
```

Since you are trying to create a new class.
Seeing you are using laravel, this can also be done like such:

```
$post = Post::firstOrCreate(['title' => $request->title, 'body' => $request->body])
```

If that does not change your error, 
Check in your App\post class if the namespace and class name are correct.